# Solidity Remix transaction reverted to initial state

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I am kinda new to solidity and I have this error that keeps popping up after I deployed the contract and run the initTest() function.
What I am trying to do is passing the string that I insert in the initTest() on the runTest so it runs and save the entire string on the blockchain.
I don't have any error when I compile the contrct, only after I deployed it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "../contracts/Code.sol";

contract CodeTest {

    ContrIdCard private _UniCode;
    bytes[] private CustID;      
    bytes[] private ContractID ;
  
   function pubblishCode (bytes memory _CustID, bytes memory _ContractID, bool _MultiCustID) private {
       _UniCode.mkCode(_CustID, _ContractID, _MultiCustID);
   }

   function initTest() public {
      uint i = 0;
      CustID[i] = "04wT9Os3uv7p"; ContractID[i++] = "e7tk6peihfcc6ece1ffbe8f8cd433ae61c1081ae6b94";
   }
   
   function runTest(bool _MultiCustID) public {
        for (uint i = 0; i<CustID.length; i++)
            pubblishCode (CustID[i], ContractID[i], _MultiCustID); 
   }
   
   function runTest() public {
        runTest(false);
   } 
}
```

The error given when I run initTest() is:
"transact to CodeTest.initTest errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information."

When I do the debug it gives me value 0  for the CustID e ContractID. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Instead of CustID[i], shouldn't you be doing CustID.push("your value here")? You haven't initialized the CustID array - it is a dynamic array.

Comment: @falopsy thank you, now the initTest() works, but it's the runTest() that gives me the same error and I don't know why

Comment: most likely a problem with your ContrIdCard contract (or its mkCode function). Without the implementation of that, it will be difficult for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

I asume that the error is comming from that when you are calling the function `runTest()` you are sending ether to it. 
In order to send ether to a function you should add the `payable` modifier to it's definition in the contract.

It should look like this:

```
 function runTest(bool _MultiCustID) public payable {
   for (uint i = 0; i<CustID.length; i++)
     pubblishCode (CustID[i], ContractID[i], _MultiCustID); 
  }
```

If you are intrested in learning more about payable functions in solidity you can check the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.2/contracts.html#receive-ether-function)